# Reset input value after alert - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reset, html-input

I have a simple input box where if the number is higher than 2, a popup message will appear.

Here is the code I am using, however I already have an `onkeyup` command on the input for something else, so I hope that won't be a problem

HTML:

```
<input id="jj_input23" type="text" value='' onkeyup='changeTransform()' />
```

Javascript:

```
if(jj_input23 > 2) {
    alert("Making the scale higher than 2 will make the preview too big");
    document.getElementById('jj_input23').value("");
}
```

After the aler message has been displayed, and the user has clicked "Ok", I want the input text to reset. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
if(jj_input23 > 2) {
    alert("Making the scale higher than 2 will make the preview too big");
    document.getElementById('jj_input23').value = "";
}
```

If you're using jQuery then you almost got it:

```
$('#jj_input23').val("");
```

Comment: I have tried clearing by replacing the value with (""), however, the input field validation is not resetting back to default. Could you please let me know how to deal with that?

Comment: @Anand are you using the built-in HTML `required` validation or something custom?

Answer (score 9):

`.value` is a property, not a function.

You want  `.value = "";`.